# Azure OracleVM: Change VM Type

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

We have an oracle 12 database installed on an Centos VM which works fine for Dev environment with few users. But when we added few more users we start having memory space and performance issue. So we decided to change the VM type to a high performance one.

Is this possible by simply choosing new VM Type in size tab for example from D2S_V3 Standard to  D4S_V3 Standard ? or if it is not possible with a live oracle machine.

Comment: Keep in mind that your VM will reboot when you change size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to change to a size which requires different hardware then you can resize VMs by first stopping your VM, selecting a new VM size and then restarting the VM. If your VM(s) are deployed using the Resource Manager (ARM) deployment model and you need to change to a size which requires different hardware then you can resize VMs by first stopping your VM, selecting a new VM size and then restarting the VM.

Note: Deallocating/Stopping the VM releases any dynamic IP addresses assigned to the VM. The OS and data disks are not affected.
I could change the VM size from standard A1 to B-series in my test lab.
See the screenshot:

Refer the below article to change the VM size by using PowerShell
[Resize a Windows VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/resize-vm?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You could resize D2S_V3 Standard to D4S_V3 Standard.

But it is need restart your VM, if you don't use static VM, the public IP maybe change.

You could resize the VM on Azure Portal.

[image]

Comment: Hi, what size you want to deploy. Some HDD  size VM could not resize to SSD directly.